# Trying to upload an image file with a html form and php, then adding file location to a sql table in another php file

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, forms

Hi i'm trying to upload an image file with a html form and php, then adding file location to a sql table in another php file. I want to use the first file to validate file size, type, and whether a file already exists with the same name before going to that second file. I have other stuff being uploaded to ther table but all of those are already working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Product Entry Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <?php
        //display errors enabled
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        
        $errMessageProdName = "Required Field";
        $errMessageProdFinish = "Required Field";
        $errMessageProdUsage = "Required Field";
        $errMessageProdCost = "Required Field";
        $errMessageProdImage = "Required Field";
        $prodName = "";
        $prodFinish = "";
        $prodUsage = "";
        $prodCost = "";
        $prodImage = "";
        $fileupload = "";
        $filetype = "";
        $filesize = "";
        $tempname = "";
        $filelocation = "";
        
        
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  
                                    
            if(isset($_POST["reset"])){
                header("Refresh:0");
                exit();
            }
            
            $prodName = checkInput($_POST["prodName"]);
            $prodFinish = checkInput($_POST["prodFinish"]);
            $prodUsage = checkInput($_POST["prodUsage"]);
            $prodCost = checkInput($_POST["prodCost"]);
            $prodCost = checkInput($_POST["prodCost"]);
            $prodImage = $_POST["prodImage"];
            
            
            
            $errMessageProdName = "Required Field";
            $errMessageProdFinish = "Required Field";
            $errMessageProdUsage = "Required Field";
            $errMessageProdCost = "Required Field";
            $errMessageProdImage = "Required Field";
            
            $validData = true;
            
            if($prodName == "") {
                $errMessageProdName = "Product name cannot be blank";
                $validData = false;
            }
            if(strlen($prodName) > 30) {
                $errMessageProdName = "Limit product name to 30 characters";
                $validData = false;
            }
            
            if($prodFinish == "") {
                $errMessageProdFinish = "Product finish cannot be blank";
                $validData = false;
            }
            if(strlen($prodFinish) > 30) {
                $errMessageProdFinish = "Limit product finish to 30 characters";
                $validData = false;
            }
            
            if($prodUsage == "") {
                $errMessageProdUsage = "Product usage cannot be blank";
                $validData = false;
            }
            if(strlen($prodUsage) > 30) {
                $errMessageProdUsage = "Limit product usage to 30 characters";
                $validData = false;
            }
            
            if($prodCost == "") {
                $errMessageProdCost = "Product cost cannot be blank";
                $validData = false;
            }
            if(is_numeric($prodCost) != 1) {
                $errMessageProdCost = "Product cost must be numeric";
                $validData = false;
            }
            
            if (isset($_POST['prodImage'])){
                $fileupload = $_FILES['prodImage']['name'];
                $filetype = $_FILES['prodImage']['type'];
                $filesize = $_FILES['prodImage']['size'];
                $tempname = $_FILES['prodImage']['tmp_name'];
                $filelocation = "images/$fileupload";
            
                if($fileupload == "") {
                    $errMessageProdImage = "Image name invalid";
                    $validData = false;
                }
                
                if (file_exists($fileLocation)){
                    $errMessageProdImage = "Image name is taken";
                    $validData = false;
                }
                
                if($filetype != "image/jpeg" || $filetype != "image/jpg" || $filetype != "image/png") {
                    $errMessageProdImage = "Product Image must be .jpeg, .jpg or .png";
                    $validData = false;
                }
                
                if (!move_uploaded_file($tempname, $filelocation)) {
                    $validData = false;             
                    switch ($_FILES['productImage']['error']) {
                        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                            $errMessageProdImage = "File exceeds the maximum size limit set by the server";
                            break;
                        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                            $errMessageProdImage = "File exceeds the maximum size limit set by the browser";
                            break;
                        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                            $errMessageProdImage = "No File Uploaded";
                            break;                      
                        default:
                            $errMessageProdImage = "File could not be uploaded";
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($validData) {
                include('doorLeverFormAddToDB.php');
                header('Location: doorLeverFormSubmitted.php');
                exit();
            }
            
        }

        function checkInput($inputData) {
            $inputData = trim($inputData);
            $inputData = stripslashes($inputData);
            $inputData = strip_tags($inputData);
            $inputData = htmlspecialchars($inputData);
            
            return $inputData;
        }
    ?>
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
          <a class="active" href="doorLeverForm.php">Add Product</a>
          <a href="updateProduct.php">Update Product</a>
          <a href="deleteProduct.php">Delete Product</a>
        </div>
        
        <h1>DOOR LEVER INVENTORY</h1>
        <h2>Product Entry Form</h2>
        <h3>Enter the door lever product details then click the submit button.</h3>

        <form id="DoorLeverForm" name="DoorLeverForm" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> >
            
            <label for="prodName">Product Name  </label><input type="text" name="prodName" id="prodName" size="20" value="<?php echo $prodName;?>"><span class="error">* 
                <?php echo $errMessageProdName;?></span><br /><br />
                
            <label for="prodFinish">Product Finish  </label><input type="text" name="prodFinish" id="prodFinish" size="20" value="<?php echo $prodFinish;?>"><span class="error">* 
                <?php echo $errMessageProdFinish;?></span><br /><br />
                
            <label for="prodUsage">Product Usage    </label><input type="text" name="prodUsage" id="prodUsage" size="20" value="<?php echo $prodUsage;?>"><span class="error">* 
                <?php echo $errMessageProdUsage;?></span><br /><br />
                
            <label for="prodCost">Product Cost  ($)</label><input type="text" name="prodCost" id="prodCost" size="20" value="<?php echo $prodCost;?>"><span class="error">* 
                <?php echo $errMessageProdCost;?></span><br /><br />
            
            <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='41943040'>Product Image <input type='file' name='prodImage' id='prodImage'><span class="error">* 
                <?php echo $errMessageProdImage;?></span><br /><br />
            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It kept coming up with undefined array key on prodImage and all the other image deatils. Now i have an isset if statement in there which made the erros go away but when i check my sql table the file location is missing. I'm not sure whether it is something missing here or it's not sending the file location to the other file

Comment: you are calling your `checkInput` function before verifying that the POST field is present  and `$prodImage = $_POST["prodImage"];` is not correct because the file will not be in the POST array it will instead be in the FILES array

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will only **destroy** data, and `stripslashes` has no business being in PHP code in 2023.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.